# What is a microsome?

Tags: cell-biology, history

[This site says:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsome)

> In cell biology, microsomes are vesicle-like artifacts re-formed from pieces of the endoplasmic reticulum (ER) when eukaryotic cells are broken-up in the laboratory; microsomes are not present in healthy, living cells.

Whereas [this other site says:](http://www.preservearticles.com/2011083012501/what-are-the-functions-of-microsomes.html)

> Microsome is another name for the smooth endoplasmic reticulum (ER).

Are they both correct? Which one is correct?

Comment: Google says "microsome
ˈmʌɪkrəsəʊm/
nounBIOLOGY
a fragment of endoplasmic reticulum and attached ribosomes obtained by the centrifugation of homogenized cells."

Comment: Or see [this](http://web.uconn.edu/mcb380/fig12-37.GIF)

Comment: @Metroplex so second site must use the word fragment?

Comment: Yes it _should_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first quote is correct. 'Microsome' is more of a *lab term*. This is because, as said they are found (re-formed) after centrifugation and as such aren't seen in an intact cell. Differential centrifugation is a technique used to separate cellular constituents into fractions. To [quote](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Proteomics/Protein_Separations_-_Centrifugation/Differential_Centrifugation#Microsomal_Fraction),

> The microsomal fraction is the pellet produced when the postmitochondrial supernatant is centrifuged at 50,000g for 60 minutes. Microsomes are small vesicles enclosed by a biological membrane. During centrifugation, the endoplasmic reticulum is fragmented into microsomes

The microsomal fraction may also contain pieces from the plasma membranes apart from those from the ER.

[image]